# Merge two arrays into one with push()

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, push

I've got follow code:

```
list1 = {
    Items: [
        {
            ID: 1,
            Name: "Zurich"
        },
        {
            ID: 2,
            Name: "London"
        },            {
            ID: 3,
            Name: "New York"
        }
    ]
};

list2 = {
    Items: [
        {
            ID: -1,
            Name: "Dummy"
        },
        {
            ID: 0,
            Name: "Dummy2"
        }
    ]
};

list1.push(list2);
```

I expect follow result:

list1:

> - 0: Object (Zurich)
> - 1: Object (London)
> - 3: Object (New York)
> - 4: Object (Dummy)
> - 5: Object (Dummy2)

But I get this one:

list1:

- 0: Object (Zurich)
- 1: Object (London)
- 2: Object (New York)
- 3: Object (Items)

  - 0: Object (Dummy)
  - 1: Object (Dummy2)

How can I get my expectet result?

Thanks and cheers.

Comment: The code you provided `list1.push(list2);` would fail with a *TypeError*. And why do you expect `4: Object (Items)` instead of `4: Object (Dummy)`?

Comment: @squint That was a typo... And I hav'nt got an error, it prints my the second result in case of my expected..But with the concat it works..

Comment: `list1` doesn't have a `.push()` method, so you must be doing something else. The `.push()` and `.concat()` methods are very different. One mutates, the other replaces. This can be an important distinction in some cases.

Comment: As to your question about `.apply()`, you need to set `list1.Items` as the "this" value of `.push()`, so that you can pass the members of `list2.Items` as individual args. You do that like this: `Array.prototype.push.apply(list1.Items, list2.Items)` or this `list1.Items.push.apply(list1.Items, list2.Items)`. Those effectively make the call end up as though you did: `list1.Items.push(list2.Items[0], list2.Items[1], ...and so on... )`

Comment: Thanks. I did it like this: 'result = Array.prototype.push.apply(list1.Items, list2.Items); console.log(result)' and it prints me 5 and not the list? Whats wrong...I think this is the number of indexes but why?

Comment: The return value of `.push()` is the new `.length`. The result is held in the mutated `list1.Items` collection. So you'd need to do `console.log(list1.Items)`.

Comment: @squint check the answer, which is marked as correct.. this worked for me. Cheers.

Comment: Yes, that's the same thing, except that the `[]` constructs a new Array just to access `.push()`, which seems wasteful. You already have an Array with `list1.Items` or you can get the method with `Array.prototype.push`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Beside [`Array#concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat), you could use `Array#push.apply` for it

```js
var list1 = { Items: [{ ID: 1, Name: "Zurich" }, { ID: 2, Name: "London" }, { ID: 3, Name: "New York" }] },
    list2 = { Items: [{ ID: -1, Name: "Dummy" }, { ID: 0, Name: "Dummy2" }] };

[].push.apply(list1.Items, list2.Items);

console.log(list1);
```

Comment: Hello thanks, this works. What about apply? I mean: list1.push.apply(list2)? I heared something about that, but I don't know how it works... Do you know this? Cheers & thanks.

Comment: Hi, i've got follow error: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined?

Comment: And please remove the concat solution in your answer, I searched one with push/push,apply.. thanks

Answer (score 4):

The question was how to do this with push() not concat():

```
for (var i = 0; i < list2.Items.length; i++) {
    list1.Items.push(list2.Items[i]);
}
```

Comment: Yes sir, thanks! I've got a question: Is there also a smart way to merge this lists without a loop but still using push? I heared something about push.apply() but I don't know how it works or how to use it.. Cheers..

Comment: @MrBuggy Yes. You can use Array.prototype.push.apply(list1.Items, list2.Items); - This works as the first argument of apply sets the value of this to list1.Items, and the second argument is an array of arguments to be passed to push.

Comment: Hi and thanks! In the answert which is marked as correct you can see the way I searched with apply. Thanks and cheers..

Answer (score 3):

Use the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator):

```
list1.Items.push(...list2.Items)
```

Spread is an ES2015 feature. Your target browsers or runtime may not support it yet, so check the [compatibility table](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-spread_(...)_operator) (or use a transpiler like [babel](https://babeljs.io/)).

Answer (score 2):

```js
list1 = {
    Items: [
        {
            ID: 1,
            Name: "Zurich"
        },
        {
            ID: 2,
            Name: "London"
        },            {
            ID: 3,
            Name: "New York"
        }
    ]
};

list2 = {
    Items: [
        {
            ID: -1,
            Name: "Dummy"
        },
        {
            ID: 0,
            Name: "Dummy2"
        }
    ]
};

list1.Items = list1.Items.concat(list2.Items);
console.log(list1);
```

Answer (score 1):

try with:

```
list2.items.forEach(function (item) {
  list1.items.push(item)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through each `items` in `list2` and then fetch them to push into `list1`.. Below is the snippet using `$.each`

```js
var list1 = {
    Items: [
        {
            ID: 1,
            Name: "Zurich"
        },
        {
            ID: 2,
            Name: "London"
        },            {
            ID: 3,
            Name: "New York"
        }
    ]
};

var list2 = {
    Items: [
        {
            ID: -1,
            Name: "Dummy"
        },
        {
            ID: 0,
            Name: "Dummy2"
        }
    ]
};

$(list2.Items).each(function(k,v){
  list1.Items.push(v);
  
})
console.log(list1);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```